# Run Postgresql on Windows 7 with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, windows, postgresql

I have installed pg on windows 7 and have an existing ruby on rails application that uses sqlite3 and want to change it to postgresql so I can deploy. I also downloaded pgAdmin but I cant start a server from it but I get the following error:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) 
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

So i edited database.yml in my rails application to be

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_database_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

and after I bundle and it doesnt give an error so pg is installed i try to rake db:create but I also get the same error as above.
but in my services.msc I cant find postgresql-[version] so I tried to start the postgresql service by running cmd in administrator

```
C:\Windows\system32>NET START postgresql-x64-9.1
The service name is invalid.
C:\Windows\system32>NET START postgresql
The service name is invalid.
```

What should I do?

Comment: add host: localhost under development

Comment: I think Rails by defaults connects to localhost. Problem seems to be with Postgres not running. Can you try and telnet to `localhost 5432`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
host: localhost
```

under development

Comment: I still get the same error. Does it matter where I add it before adapter: of after it

Comment: is your postgres service running? It seems like your postgres is not running

Comment: Is this your first installation of postgres?

Comment: yes it is and as I stated I cant find it in services.msc and I dont know how to run it